# Facebook Graph Api - Retrieve only Wall posts that contain a photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I need to retrieve wall posts from Facebook for a given account, but I'm only interested in posts that contain a photo.  Is there a way to add such a filter to a Facebook graph api query?  Something like:

> https://graph.facebook.com/DigitasLBiNL?fields=feed&type=photo

The facebook data contains a `type` property which comes back as `photo`, so I would think this would be possible, but I haven't had any luck going through the facebook sdk documentation or tinkering around.

I know I could do the filtering myself, but I'd prefer to be able to keep the `paging` property that facebook returns.

Comment: Graph API doesn’t offer much in terms of filtering as of now. FQL does, but is deprecated – when it will finally be removed, they will most likely add filtering capabilities to the API, but right now I don’t think what you want is possible with Graph API.

Comment: Well that's disappointing, but thanks for sharing.

Comment: I'm struggling with a similar issue. I notice when requesting an edge, there is a syntax "with(<value>)" which I can't find in the documentation.  Haven't worked out how it can be used, Maybe it can't , but thought I'd mention in case you or someone else can work it out :)

Comment: @RobDenBoer - I've also seen the `with` property in the Graph API Explorer, but can't figure out a way to use it.  There doesn't seam to be a way to specify a key value pair (type=photo) to restrict the result set.  Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: `with` can only be used to filter on posts containing a location. The docs are here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/feed#read

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The edges

- `/{user_id}/home` (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/home#read)
- `/{user_id}/feed` (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/feed#read)

should (as per documentation) both be able to take a `filter` paramenter, containing filter keys from the `stream_filter` FQL table (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream_filter/).

If I run the FQL

```
select name, value, type, filter_key from stream_filter where uid=me()
```

I get the following result:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "News Feed", 
      "value": null, 
      "type": "newsfeed", 
      "filter_key": "nf"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Status Updates", 
      "value": 2915120374, 
      "type": "application", 
      "filter_key": "app_2915120374"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Photos", 
      "value": 2305272732, 
      "type": "application", 
      "filter_key": "app_2305272732"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Links", 
      "value": 2309869772, 
      "type": "application", 
      "filter_key": "app_2309869772"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Pages", 
      "value": null, 
      "type": "public_profiles", 
      "filter_key": "pp"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Video", 
      "value": 2392950137, 
      "type": "application", 
      "filter_key": "app_2392950137"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Notes", 
      "value": 2347471856, 
      "type": "application", 
      "filter_key": "app_2347471856"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Groups", 
      "value": 2361831622, 
      "type": "application", 
      "filter_key": "app_2361831622"
    }
  ]
}
```

So, if I choose `app_2305272732` as filter key for the photos, I am able to run the follwoing Graph API request successfully:

```
/me/home?filter=app_2305272732&limit=3
```

This gives me the three most recent photo posts from my newsfeed.

You want to do this for User/Page feeds (Pages are not supported for filtering according to the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/feed#read), so I tried this:

```
/me/feed?filter=app_2305272732&limit=3
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't return only photo posts, at least for me. So I think this is a bug in the Facebook Graph API.

Comment: Thanks for the post.  It sounds like it will just be easier to do the filtering myself, so I'm going to take that approach.

Comment: You're welcome, and sorry that FB doesn't works as documented.

Comment: Damn Zuckerberg! *shakes fist*

Comment: You're right :-) I was thinking of opening a bug for this issue, but from further experience I know that's a hurthful path to walk down...

Answer (score 1):

According to

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/stream-filter/

you can use the `type` filter with value `photo`